# plt.gca() opens a blank canvas along with my graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a block of python code from a larger file

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#Some data to show the problem
PlotData = [[I for I in range(1000)], [np.sqrt(I) for I in range (1000)]]

#problem line
plt.gca().set_xlim([PlotData[0][0],PlotData[0][len(PlotData[0])-1]])

Fig, Ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize = (32, 24))
Ax.plot(PlotData[0], PlotData[1])
Ax.set_title("Sqrt(X)", fontsize = 24)
Ax.set_xlabel("X", fontsize = 20)
Ax.set_ylabel("Y", fontsize = 20)
figManager = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
figManager.window.showMaximized()
plt.show()
```

and whenever I run it it perfectly displays my data but it also opens a second blank canvas. However if I remove the line `plt.gca().set_xlim([PlotData[0][0],PlotData[0][len(PlotData[0])-1]])` it doesn't show the blank canvas anymore. In my code I sometimes perform some operations on the data so I need to have that line, how do I prevent this blank canvas from appearing?

Thanks in advance to anyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`plt.gca()` is an operation which "**g**ets the **c**urrent **a**xes". If an Axes object doesn't yet exist, it will create one for you.

You perform this operation before creating your figure with `plt.subplots`. Which means you have the figure and axes which you then put your plot on, and the previously created axes (the blank window you see).

The solution is to set the `xlim` after you have already created the Axes. So move `plt.subplots` above that line, or move that line down (then you don't need to `plt.gca().set_xlim()`, you can just use `Ax.set_xlim()`.

Currently that line of code is not doing anything to your plot anyway, since you are setting the x-limits on a different Axes instance to the one you plot your data on.